# TableView Lagging when slow scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, smooth-scrolling

I have problem with smooth scrolling on my `UITableViewCell`. 
When I scroll in my `UITableView` slowly I get 30-40 FPS and my cells are jumping (first on top and last on bottom).

When I scroll fast I get 55-60 FPS, cells aren't jumping and all is good.

FPS was measured by Profile.

Also when I'm scrolling CPU usege is ~ 15-25 %

Im using `UIStoryboard` to create the cell, `Realm DB`, and `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Here is my `UITableView` Code:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let stop = getStop(indexPath: indexPath)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "stop", for: indexPath) as! StopTableViewCell
    cell.configure(model: stop)
    return cell        
 }
```

Here is cell code:

```
class StopTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var status: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var number: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var date: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var name: UnderLinedLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var address: UnderLinedLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var phone: UnderLinedLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var milage: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    name.text = nil
    address.text = nil
    phone.text = nil
    milage.text = nil
    number.text =  nil
    date.text = nil
}

func calculateEstimateRoute(to lat: Double, lon: Double) -> String {
    let distance = LocationManager.Instance.actualLocation.distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon))
    let isMetric = NSLocale.current.usesMetricSystem
    let measurment = Measurement(value: distance, unit: UnitLength.meters)
    var estimateRoute = !isMetric ? measurment.converted(to: UnitLength.miles) : measurment.converted(to: UnitLength.kilometers)
    estimateRoute.value = round(estimateRoute.value)
    return "~" + String(describing: estimateRoute)
}

func configure<T>(model: T) {
    if let stop = model as? Stop {
        name.text = stop.name
        address.text = stop.address1 + "\n" + stop.address2
        phone.text = stop.phone
        phone.isHidden = stop.phone.isEmpty
        milage.text = calculateEstimateRoute(to: stop.lat, lon: stop.lng)
        number.text =  "# " + stop.refno
        date.text = stop.departtime
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}
```

}

Here is cell Via storyboard: 
[image]

Maybe i must create 3 cells one for top orangeView, second for center content and third of bottom buttons view?

Here is :

```
func getStop<S: Stop>(indexPath: IndexPath) -> S {
    switch segmentIndex {
    case 0:
        return stops.ASSIGNED[indexPath.row] as! S
    case 1:
        return stops.UNASSIGNED[indexPath.row] as! S
    default:
        return Stop() as! S
    }
}
```

In header i have UISegmentedControl

Comment: May I see your getStop()? It’s likely your realm query is slow

Comment: Why use a generic in the `configure()` function? Surely you could pass in `Stop` here?

Comment: The issue might be related to `calculateEstimateRoute(to:lon:)`. This function is taking time to calculate. You might want to move this calculation to a background thread.

Comment: I am having the same problem. It is related to UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at this and wondering, how long does`calculateEstimateRoute` take to complete? That seems to be the most likely bottleneck.

I suggest you run Instruments with Time Profiler and see how much processor power is dedicated to that function. If it's significant, you might consider pushing that function onto a background thread - maybe using an operation queue so that calls can be cancelled in `prepareForReuse`. I've used similar techniques with cells containing images, since loading images can be time-consuming.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are calculating your distance information each time you populate the cell.

you need to remember that the cells are constantly getting populated as you scroll through the visible list of cells on your device. this means that as you scroll up and down you are repeatably calculating the value.

maybe this is your intent because the user can be traveling? I don't know your use case so I can offer the following as an idea.

Change your data source just provide this information as part of your Stop object. If you need to update the distance information based on users location and you want to handle the fact that they can be in motion you should use startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges() and as the location is updating you calculate estimated route.

You can use the following for information on getting location updates:

subscribe to location updates.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati

method you'll need to implement to get location updates.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager